# How to use Xfce4-display-settings terminal commands?

Tags: xfce, command-line, display-manager

What I want is a terminal command that would activate internal display in case it is de-activated in Xfce. (Then, I could run this command by a script+shortkey and get a solution to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/259743/47206) problem). The help of Xfce4-display-settings gives this

```
~ $ xfce4-display-settings -h
Usage:
  xfce4-display-settings [OPTION...]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                    Show help options
  --help-all                    Show all help options
  --help-gtk                    Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -s, --socket-id=SOCKET ID     Settings manager socket
  -v, --version                 Version information
  -m, --minimal                 Minimal interface to set up an external output
  --display=DISPLAY             X display to use
```

I am interested in this: `--display=DISPLAY             X display to use`

I guess it means that the command `xfce4-display-settings --display=DISPLAY` would activate the given DISPLAY.

**What to enter there in place of `DISPLAY` that would be the internal display?**

What for the external display?

Comment: You probably want to look at the `xrandr` command instead of `xfce4-display-settings`.

Comment: @chronitis: does it have a gui? i am more used with `lxrandr` and `arandr`, both can easily be used with shortkeys. but i was wondering what's with that xfce4 display option specifically. so, considering that the other more general question is solved for me (http://askubuntu.com/a/259765/47206) i would be interested here just in a specific answer on what to enter in that command instead of `DISPLAY`. shouldn't that command open THAT display?

Comment: `xrandr` is a command line interface to the X resize-and-rotate ("`randr`") API. `xfce4-display-settings` and the Unity/GNOME display settings applet will use the same API, and I suppose could be said to be GUIs for it.

Comment: The `--display` option to `xfce4-display-settings` will I assume take an X screen (as per the environment variable `$DISPLAY`, eg `:0.0`). This is unlikely to be useful to you - multiple monitors are treated as a single X screen (look up `xinerama`) - this option is used if you're running multiple thin clients off one machine or using an X server on a remote machine.

Comment: @chronitis: so, in a way that nullifies my question, for the possible answer is of no use to me. or to keep it for others you might paste as answer your last comment, and ill set is accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `--display` option to `xfce4-display-settings` will I assume take an X screen (as per the environment variable `$DISPLAY`, eg `:0.0`).

This is unlikely to be useful to you - multiple monitors are treated as a single large X screen, with the `xinerama` X extension providing hints on the actual monitor boundaries to window managers so that, eg maximising a window will maximise it to fill only one monitor.

This option is useful if you are running multiple thin clients off a single machine, or using X over SSH (in which case your `$DISPLAY` will look something like `remotehost:7.0`).