# Command to cycle displays in Xfce

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, display, xfce, multiple-monitors

One can change displays in Xfce (in 14.04) from GUI by choosing between:

```
Laptop
Mirror Displays
Extend to the Right
Monitor
```

Is there a command to cycle between these options?

(So that I associate it to a shortkey and then just press that key to cycle displays directly, that is, without GUI, without opening the Display window, selecting, closing, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/disper.1.html) about **Disper**. See link for details.

It can be installed from Synaptic or the terminal.

The command to cycle between clone, extended, internal and external displays should be like this:

> disper --cycle-stages='-e : -c : -S : -s' --cycle

In that case, it would extend to the right. To cycle between the same options but extend to the left:

> disper --direction=left --cycle-stages='-e : -c : -S : -s' --cycle

The command can be then associated to a short-key.

[image]

The simplest shortkey might be the Display key (XF86Display) if there is one available on the keyboard. (Because of a bug, in my case that involves [an interference with the Super key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176652/32012), so that I prefer to use XF86HomePage.)

Disper will detect displays and use the maximal resolutions by default. If no external display is connected, nothing will happen when the short-key is touched.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a new keyboard shortcut is possible (in Settings -> Keyboard -> Application shortcuts), but finding the right terminal command...

**`xrandr`** can change the resolution, I know it works if you're using one monitor, it's man page could have more info on what you'd like to do, other answers advise using it...? Here's a clip from it's man page:

> `--left-of, --right-of, --above, --below, --same-as another-output`
>   Use one of these options to position the output relative to the position of another
>   output.  This  allows convenient tiling of outputs within the screen.  The position
>   is always computed relative to the new position of the other output, so it  is  not
>                 valid to say --output a --left-of b --output b --left-of a.
>
> `--off`  Disables the output.
>
> `--reflect reflection`
>   Reflection  can  be  one of 'normal' 'x', 'y' or 'xy'. This causes
>   the output contents to be reflected across the specified axes.

Searching for the "display" program, with `dpkg -S display` then searching that for xfce found the .desktop file `/usr/share/applications/xfce-display-settings.desktop`, and it's target `xfce4-settings: /usr/bin/xfce4-display-settings`. It has a very basic man page, but a search on this site found:

- [How do I setup dual monitors in XFCE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62681/how-do-i-setup-dual-monitors-in-xfce) - Uses `xrandr --left-of`
- [using a Notebook with two external screens unter xfce with xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/a/259748) - Less than ideal advice: *"To configurate xrandr is not difficult, just have a look at the manpages. Some "Try and Error" helped me"*

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can also use the keyboard arrows `left` and `right` to cycle through the options (in screenshot I've selected the right-most option) and then use `enter` to activate the desired option.

Comment: that is obvious. i was looking for a shortkey associated to one single command that would cycle display without opening a GUI etc

Comment: I see. Perhaps you can make this more clear in the question...

Comment: did that now, i hope it is clearer

Comment: In case anyone wonders, the command to display the visual mode selector as depicted in this answer is `xfce4-display-settings --minimal`. This command is by default assigned to CTRL+ALT+P but can be assigned to a key combination of your choice (in Keyboard Settings->Application Shortcuts) to show the mode selector. Pressing the key combination (thus executing the command) a second time will not cycle through the modes (as it is the case in Windows). You will have to use a mouse or arrow keys to pick the desired mode.