# Kubutnu 16.04 Nvidia (optimus) external monitor shows cloning + panning

Tags: drivers, xorg, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus

I have a weird problem using Kubuntu 16.04 on my Dell XPS 501X with Nvidia graphics. Upon connecting an external monitor at HDMI, the two monitors work, but if I scroll my mouse to access second monitor the whole thing pans and clones on my external monitor. This is a view of my external screen - which shows the laptop screen too. This is best seen in the video below.

[image: This scene shows on external monitor, and the laptop screen only shows the second (spotify) screen]

[Here is a link to video demonstrating this - very sory for the noisy fan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8g2x92560kceHZiSXRfVWRSMkk/view?usp=sharing)

Is there a solution to this problem? I am using 361.42 drivers from Nvidia. The display confg screen, xserver settings and Nvidia config look like this:

[image: Display configuration]

[image: Xserver settings show panned display]

[image: Nvidia config]

I there something I am missing?? Any help will be very much appreciated as this is sort of crippling and I am thinking about going back to Windows!!

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem from a different perspective. Your `xrandr` obviously recognizes both screens, hence, you can use them by manually changing between them by using the command line. That is, of course, quite inconvenient. So you might want to install a program called [disper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/disper.1.html) and set it to a hotkey as explained [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/578028/308869).

Shortly, just install `disper` using `apt-get` and try

> disper --cycle-stages='-e : -c : -S : -s' --cycle

May be it will solve your problem for now.

Comment: Hey Ufos, That suggestion works, thanks for the help. I still hope that there is a solution for this, as it is not ideal. I can atleast work with this now though.